# Don't run command when command substitution result is blank

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I have the following code to run `pylint` on all files in a Git repository with file extension `.py`, fed by command substitution.

```bsh
pylint $(git ls-files '*.py')
```

The script runs just fine except when there are no files matching the pattern.  However, the `pylint` utility gives a verbose help message when it is called with no files, which is not what I want - I don't want to call `pylint` at all.

So, could I ask for some help on how best to test if any files match the filename pattern before calling `pylint`?

I'm a `pylint` and `bash` newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a command substitution at all.  Instead, pass the data from `git ls-files` to `xargs` using a pipe and let `xargs` run `pylint` on the generated list of files:

```bsh
git ls-files -z '*.py' | xargs -0 -r pylint
```

This passes the list of files from the `git` command to `xargs` as a `\0`-delimited list.  The `xargs` utility would run `pylint` with names read from `git`, but with `-r`, it would not run the utility if the list was empty.

This solves three issues:

1. By passing the pathnames as a `\0`-delimited list, it supports files with names containing newlines and other whitespaces.
2. By reading from the pipe and running `pylint` on as large batches of files as possible, we are able to handle the case when `git ls-files` produces so much data that using the command substitution would fail with "argument list too long".
3. It does not run `pylint` if the list is empty.

This answer assumes using an `xargs` implementation that has the non-standard (but common) options `-0` and `-r`.

Comment: i was thinking to something similar, like : `xargs -a <(git ls-files -z '*.p') -ri -- pylint {}` . 
But your is better. +1

Comment: Awesome thanks for the response - a lot of learning points for me